# Paged, Multi-Poco queries with Petapoco?

Tags: petapoco

PetaPoco is great and covers [paged queries](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/74/PetaPoco-Paged-Queries) and [Multi-Poco mapping](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/115/PetaPoco-Mapping-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-One-Relationships), but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do them together?

**Edit:**

Here's the repository method I use to get MultiPoco data:

```
// variables, used in multiple repo methods
private readonly string _selectClause = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM Clients 
                                                                    OUTER APPLY 
                                                            (SELECT TOP 1* From Events 
                                                                 WHERE Events.EndDateTime >= '{0}'
                                                                 AND Events.ClientId = Clients.Id
                                                            ) Events 
                                                           WHERE Clients.TenantId=@0", DateTime.UtcNow);

private readonly string _orderbyClause = "ORDER BY Clients.Lastname";

// method

public new IEnumerable<Client> AllByTenantAndStatus(Status status)
{
    string sql = String.Format("{0} AND Clients.Status=@1 {1}", _selectClause, _orderbyClause);

    // using external relator
    // return Db.Fetch<Client, Event, Client>(new ClientEventRelator().MapIt,
    //                                               sql, _tenantResolver.CurrentTenantId, status);

    return Db.Fetch<Client, Event>(sql, _tenantResolver.CurrentTenantId, status);
}
```

Method declarations in Petapoco.cs

```
public Page<T> Page<T>(long page, long itemsPerPage, string sql, params object[] args)
```

and

```
public void BuildPageQueries<T>(long skip, long take, string sql, ref object[] args, out string sqlCount, out string sqlPage)
```

both of which accept a single return type parameter.

So I guess my question is that what's the best approach to use the Paged query functionality provided in PetaPoco with MultiPoco queries, as the method provided only works with a single return type?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details of your problem for anyone to help. There shouldn't be a problem with paged multipoco mapping

Comment: @Gareth, added more detail above. Hopefully the question makes more sense now

Comment: Is there a bug in the _selectClause = string.Format()? You use {1} but there is only a single parameter to Format() so it should be {0}

Comment: Sorry that was a typo here in the question, the {0} was Clients.TenantId, but I put that in the sql itself, and forgot to change {1] to {0}

Comment: Old question I know, but just wondering if you found a solution for this @seekay?

Answer (score 1):

It is complicated, especially because PetaPoco wants to support old DB systems. It means there are used clauses like ROW_NUMBER() OVER... for pagination and when PetaPoco is counting total numbers of records there are often conflicts. Consider:

```
select * from articles join authors on articles.authorid = authors.id
```

In case you will have name of the column `id` on `articles` and `authors` table, there is gonna be conflict in automatic generated queries.

**SOLUTION**

In case you want to work with new version of SQL Server that supports OFFSET / FETCH NEXT you can write simple method for your purpose that will use another methods from PetaPoco. F.e.:

```
public partial class Database // Create Database class partial and extend it
{
    public Page<TRet> PagedFetch<T1, T2, T3, TRet>(long page, long itemsPerPage, Func<T1, T2, T3, TRet> cb,
        string sql, params object[] args)
    {
        string sqlCount, sqlPage;
        BuildPageQueries<TRet>((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage, sql, ref args, out sqlCount, out sqlPage);

        sql = string.Format("{0} offset {1} rows fetch next {2} rows only", sql, (page - 1) * itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage);

        var data = Fetch(cb, sql, args);

        var result = new Page<TRet>
        {
            Items = data,
            TotalItems = ExecuteScalar<long>(sqlCount),
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = itemsPerPage
        };

        result.TotalPages = result.TotalItems/itemsPerPage;

        if ((result.TotalItems % itemsPerPage) != 0)
            result.TotalPages++;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally, dont forget, that you can use OFFSET just when you have sorted data. It means, you should finish your SQL query with "order by something desc" for example.