# Incorrect syntax near 'PETA_PAGED' added by peta poco .net pagination query

Tags: c#, .net, database, petapoco

i am getting Incorrect syntax near 'PETA_PAGED' where i was using the tenantaware database to get the data from the data base and here is the query which i was using

```
select Id, Name from ListView where IsPartOf = 0
```

and after coming to the this step it is appending

```
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME) PETA_RN, ID, NAME FROM LISTVIEW  WHERE  TenantId = '0000-000-0000-0000-0000'  and ( ISPARTOF=0 ) PETA_PAGED ORDER BY  NAME) PETA_RN, ID, NAME FROM LISTVIEW WHERE ISPARTOF=0 PETA_PAGED WHERE PETA_RN > @0 AND PETA_RN <= @1"
```

and exception i am getting **{"Incorrect syntax near 'PETA_PAGED'."}**

service call i am using

```
 var query = "select Id, Name from ListView where IsPartOf =0";

Page<Data.ListView> pagedData = this.TenantAwareDB.Page<Data.ListView>(pagedQuery.PageIndex, pagedQuery.PageSize, new Sql(query));
```

Comment: @mjwills i just updated my query you can check now

Comment: The SQL you get is very unusual ... You might find a solution in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763632/paged-multi-poco-queries-with-petapoco

Answer (score 0):

Try this Brother, It's working for me.

```
var query = "select Id, Name from ListView where IsPartOf =0";
query = query.Append(string.Format("OFFSET ({0} - 1) * {1} ROWS FETCH NEXT {1} ROWS ONLY", pageNo, pageSize));
Page<Data.ListView> pagedData = this.TenantAwareDB.Page<Data.ListView>(new Sql(query));
```